# UnboundLocalError when use element tree to parse XML in plugin QGIS

Tags: python, xml, parsing, qgis

I make plugin to open XML and read it then parse it to show some information, this is code I use

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_latih import Ui_latih
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class latihDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_latih()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        cariButton = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(cariButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.cari)

    def cari(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineFile.setText(filename)

        #panggil isi data
        self.isiDataFile(filename)

    def isiDataFile(self, nmfile):
        #buka dengan open mode baca
        teksFile = open(nmfile, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textFile.setText(teksFile)

       #parse XML FIle
        self.parsethis(teksFile)

    def parsethis(self, parse):
        doc =  ETree.fromstring(parse)
        for elem in doc.findall('{Default_Config/gco#}Integer'):
            a=elem.tag, elem.text
        print a


        self.ui.lineSkala.setText(a)
```

I parse a big xml file (total 14 page when i print it) and one line that i want to parse showed like this

```
<gmd:denominator>
<gco:Integer>ValueScale</gco:Integer>
</gmd:denominator>
```

I want to put ValueScale to show in QlineEdit and i get error message say:

```
File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 65, in parsethis
    self.ui.lineSkala.setText(a)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: yes that all of my code, sorry for my bad english, because i have a little understanding in english

Comment: my mistake, that error message is from second try code, i edited it now... my apologize

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies probably here:

```
   for elem in doc.findall('{Default_Config/gco#}Integer'):
            a=elem.tag, elem.text
        print a

   self.ui.lineSkala.setText(a)
```

If `doc.findall` returns `None`, there will be no `a`.
You need to check for the presence of a:

```
try:
    self.ui.lineSkala.setText(a)
except (UnboundLocalError, NameError):
    do_here_something_else...
```